# regular expression test vocabulary zero or more times

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace "table1" to "tableA", so I wrote a regular expression to test sql statement.

```
String sql1 = "select * from table1";
String sql2 = "select * from table1 where x=123";

String pattern = "from\\s(.*)(where|)";
System.out.println(sql1.replaceFirst(pattern, "from tableA $2"));
System.out.println(sql2.replaceFirst(pattern, "from tableA $2"));
```

First result of print is correct, but second print is lack of "where... "

If I change pattern to `String pattern = "from\\s(.*)(where)";` , without |, then sql2 can be replaced, but sql1 won't be matched.

How do I combine the two condition into one pattern?

Comment: Why don't you just search for `table1` and replace with `tableA`??? I don't see any need for regular expressions here.

Comment: Well, `replaceFirst("\\btable1\\b", "tableA")` should be enough.

Comment: The `.*` matches everything, and because the empt string is allowed after the match, no backtracking is required to satisfy the match.

Answer (score 0):

Include an asterisk after the optional `(where|)`. You may now ignore the pipe character `|` in your pattern

```
String pattern = "from\\s(.*)(where|)\*";
```

or

```
String pattern = "from\\s(.*)(where)\*";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to address your current issue with the sample queries you provided: the `|` alternation in `(where|)` makes matching `where` optional. Thus, `.*` matches the rest of the string in the first case, and up to the last occurrence of `where` (luckily, it is the only `where` in the second query).

What you can use here to replace `from` with 1+ word characters is a mere

```
replaceFirst("from\\s+\\w+", "from tableA")
```

If you need to match anything between from and the first `where` OR the end of string, you can use

```
replaceFirst("from\\s++.*?(?=where|$)", "from tableA")
```

where

- `from` - matches `from` (you may enclose it with `\\b` to ensure a whole word match)
- `\\s++`  - 1+ whitespaces (possessively quantified to avoid backtracking)
- `.*?` - 0+ chars other than a newline up to the first
- `(?=where|$)` - `where` (you may enclose it with `\\b`) or the end of string (`$`).